# Display sentences based on a regEx match using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get list of all sentences that contain "We" using RegEx

This is what I have but its not working.

```
var text = "He has demonstrated their commitment to exceptional customer service. We also provide a better understanding of their customers' evolving needs. We are thrilled to be their technology partner on this journey, this text shouldn't be included because it doesn't have a he or we.";
var matches = [];
const regex = /We/g;
var counter = 0;
var res;

res = text.match(regex);
if (res) {
    console.log("Text: " + res);
    counter++;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Clarify your problem. What is not working? What is the expected output?

Comment: You will need to define what you mean by "sentence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your ***sentences*** end with one of `.,!?` you could use

```js
var text = "He has demonstrated their commitment to exceptional customer service. We also provide a better understanding of their customers' evolving needs. We are thrilled to be their technology partner on this journey, this text shouldn't be included because it doesn't have a he or we.";
var matches;
const regex = /[^.!,?]*We[^.!,?]*[.!,?]/g;
var counter = 0;
var res;

matches = text.match(regex);
if (matches) {
  matches.forEach(match => console.log('Text:' + match));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will come back to this post and clean it up later, but this should work:

```js
var text = "He has demonstrated their commitment to exceptional customer service. We also provide a better understanding of their customers' evolving needs. We are thrilled to be their technology partner on this journey, this text shouldn't be included because it doesn't have a he or we.";

const out = text.match(/[^\.]*we[^\.]*/gi);

console.log(out);
```